# How do you filter an NSMutable Array that contains core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have an array that it is populated by core data as follows.

NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults  = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsFromContext:@"Spot" :@"Name" :YES :managedObjectContext];

It looks like this in the console.

(entity: Spot; id: 0x4b7e580  ; data: {
    CityToProvince = 0x4b7dbd0 ;
    Description = "Friend";
    Email = "bla@bla.com";
    Age = 21;
    Name = "Adam";
    Phone = "+44175240";
}),

How can i filter the array to remove anyone who is over a certain age? or use values in the array to make calculations?

Please help i have been stuck for ages on this. Code would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785462/how-do-you-delete-rows-from-uitableview

Answer (score 1):

You construct an `NSPredicate` and then call `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` upon the array to get back a filtered array.

Comment: Thanks for another great Core-Data answer marcus.  Helped me implement filtering in my table-view with ease.